# Email Form Module in Joomla 3.1 - Uses Joomla Mailer and PHP

Tags: php, forms, email, joomla3.0

I have been trying for in excess of a week at any spare opportunity to make this email form work. It's based on a web tutorial for what appears to be a far earlier version of Joomla, as much of it's language appears to have been superseded. I've changed bits around accordingly, but may have missed some rather obvious parts, as I'm probably a little out of my depth with this, but am determined to get it right!

I'm writing this as a module so I can call it at any point on a Joomla page by using {loadmodule contact}.

The form loads up on the page correctly, except when I make certain changes and introduce a HTTP internal server error (500) with no further explanation.

If I leave the form action as "index.php" as the tutorial had, it finishes me up on the index page of the Joomla site with no email. If I take the action out, as other tutorials or answers on here recommend, it clears the form, but appears to take a moment or two to process what's there - but still no email.

There's nothing wrong with the Joomla install or it's ability to email - it's a fresh install with two pages, and it's been tested as sending user confirmation emails correctly.

I'm rusty with PHP and have spent most of my time going over this character by character and searching commands to ensure I've got them right, so it might be something simple that I've just missed. I may also have the logic of the entire thing wrong, but it *seems* right to me.

There's very little about writing this type of thing from scratch online at all - most discussions either relate to, or end up suggesting, a prewritten module or component, none of which are clean or simple enough, or able to meet the ease of calling it as described above.

Okay, here goes. The module is called mod_contact, and has the following base PHP file.

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not permitted.');

$document =& JFactory::GetDocument();
$document->addStyleSheet(JURI::base() . 'modules/mod_contact/css/contact.css');
$document->addScript(JURI::base() . 'modules/mod_contact/js/contact.js');

$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

$c_send = JRequest::getVar('c_send', 'false');

switch($c_send){

    case 'true':

    $c_name = $jinput->get('c_name', 'No Name');
    $c_email = $jinput->get('c_email', 'No Email Address');
    $c_telephone = $jinput->get('c_telephone', 'No Telephone Number');
    $c_message = $jinput->get('c_message', 'No Message');

    $c_send = ModContactHelper::SendMail($c_send, $c_name, $c_email, $c_telephone, $c_message);

    if($c_send !== true) {
        echo 'Error Sending Email: ' . $c_send->message;

        require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_contact',
                  'confirmation_tmpl'));
        break;

    default:
    require(JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_contact',
              'default_tmpl'));

}

?>
```

The module has a helper.php file that takes care of the mailing, and is meant to return a value of 'true' for $c_send, which causes the template to change from 'default' to 'confirmation'. I've yet to see it display the confirmation template - the best it's done is clear the form.

Here is the helper.php file.

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct access to this location is not permitted.');

class ModContactHelper {
public function SendMail($c_send, $c_name, $c_email, $c_telephone, $c_message) {

    # Fetch Joomla Email Configuration

    $config = JFactory::getConfig();


    # Fetch JMail (Global Mail Object) through the JFactory Object.

    $mailer = JFactory::getMailer();


    # Set Sender to Name and Email Address from Contact Form

    $mailer->setSender($c_email, $c_name);


    # Set Subject Line

    $mailer->setSubject('Message from Website Contact Form');


    # Set Recipient to the Site Email Address, as defined in Joomla

    $c_recipient = $config->getValue('config.mailfrom');
    $mailer->addRecipient($c_recipient);


    # Set Email Content

    $c_body = "The following email was submitted via the Website Contact Form.<br />";
    $c_body.= "<br />
    $c_body.= "Name:        ".$c_name."<br />";
    $c_body.= "Email Address:   ".$c_email."<br />";
    $c_body.= "Contact Number:  ".$c_telephone."<br />";
    $c_body.= "<br />";
    $c_body.= "Message:     ".$c_message."<br />";

    $mailer->setBody($c_body);
    $mailer->IsHTML(true);

    $c_send =& $mailer->Send();

    return $c_send;

}

}

?>
```

I've tried switching out some of the variables, such as the recipient's email address with just an email address, but still no luck.

Lastly, here is the default template - default_tmpl.php. I've left the action in for reference.

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not permitted.');
?>

<div id="mod_contact">

<form action="index.php" method="post" id="c_form">
  <input name="c_send" type="hidden" value="send"/>
  <p><label for "name">Name</label><input name="c_name" type="text" id="c_name" size="30"/></p>
  <p><label for "email">Email Address</label><input name="c_email" type="text" id="c_email" size="30"/></p>
  <p><label for "telephone">Telephone Number</label><input name="c_telephone" type="text" id="c_telephone" size="30"/></p>
  <p>
  <label for "question">How can I help?</label><textarea name="c_message" cols="60" rows="10" class="c_message"></textarea></p>
  <p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
</form>

</div>
```

Thanks so much for any help anybody is able to offer. If needed, I can supply the full module as a ZIP file, for ease of installation and testing if anybody wants to play with it that far.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already got it working but recently I was trying the same thing by creating my first module and struggled quite a bit initially.

I can see following couple of things that needs correction in you code:
- The first file (that's mod_contact.php) in your case statement for variable "c_send" you are looking for value 'true' to be sent on form submission but you are sending value 'send" in your default_tmpl. You need to either compare string with "send' or send a value of "true" from default_tmpl.
- In the  tag skip the action part completely to return back to mod_contact.php.

Hope that helps.